# Many Kubernetes pods get stuck with Completed and Error status

Tags: kubernetes

Many pods get stuck with Completed or Error status and they can hang like that for 30-40 days.
Sometimes in some namespaces, I see things like this appear and disappear, but mostly it just accumulates.

They basically end up with this error: The node was low on resource: memory.
But this is an expected error due to the parameters:
--eviction-hard=memory.available<15%
--eviction-soft=memory.available<30%

```
blackbox-exporter                      blackbox-exporter-prometheus-blackbox-exporter-6c45969dbc-6dcnl   0/1     Completed           0                20d     100.96.113.92  
blackbox-exporter                      blackbox-exporter-prometheus-blackbox-exporter-6c45969dbc-gt72t   0/1     Completed           0                20d     100.96.111.127 
blackbox-exporter                      blackbox-exporter-prometheus-blackbox-exporter-6c45969dbc-xzq9j   0/1     Completed           0                17d     100.96.101.165 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-2hhs2                         0/1     Error               0                12d     100.96.102.61  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-2x5mp                         0/1     Error               0                23d     100.96.111.29  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-4hnh6                         0/1     Error               0                27d     100.96.101.242 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-4zhzl                         0/1     Error               0                25d     100.96.101.98  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-5945w                         0/1     Error               0                27d     100.96.120.69  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-6kvvp                         0/1     Error               0                24d     100.96.110.12  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-6qjmm                         0/1     Error               0                24d     100.96.113.120 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-6xkz8                         0/1     Error               0                31d     100.96.29.152  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-6zvfb                         0/1     Error               0                30d     100.96.112.245 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-72dsg                         0/1     Error               0                24d     100.96.105.175 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-7bqx7                         0/1     Error               0                24d     100.96.87.245  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-8s9xx                         0/1     Error               0                26d     100.96.112.102 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-8sjwg                         0/1     Error               0                31d     100.96.110.78  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-99xjc                         0/1     Error               0                27d     100.96.110.237 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-9llgf                         0/1     Error               0                26d     100.96.29.173  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-9q6xj                         0/1     Error               0                31d     100.96.111.1   
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-9ss44                         0/1     Error               0                25d     100.96.111.114 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-b7sxt                         0/1     Error               0                23d     100.96.29.64   
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-bhdrg                         0/1     Error               0                30d     100.96.29.178  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-clgmf                         0/1     Error               0                26d     100.96.105.210 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-cm9n8                         0/1     Error               0                27d     100.96.113.39  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-cwwcg                         0/1     Error               0                24d     100.96.114.2   
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-czz5p                         0/1     Error               0                23d     100.96.111.64  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-d5lkn                         0/1     Error               0                26d     100.96.101.152 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-dstl8                         0/1     Error               0                27d     100.96.120.66  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-gdf6r                         0/1     Error               0                20d     100.96.101.181 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-gzkjj                         0/1     Error               0                26d     100.96.101.114 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-hmlgc                         0/1     Error               0                27d     100.96.110.218 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-j2jxm                         0/1     Error               0                26d     100.96.105.218 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-j2qff                         0/1     Error               0                26d     100.96.111.37  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-j6m7t                         0/1     Error               0                12d     100.96.111.127 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-jdmhn                         0/1     Error               0                26d     100.96.113.21  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-jlmbk                         0/1     Error               0                20d     100.96.102.94  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-jztnq                         0/1     Error               0                30d     100.96.113.26  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-l8xcp                         0/1     Error               0                31d     100.96.101.120 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-ld7mm                         0/1     Error               0                26d     100.96.114.123 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-mhfvc                         0/1     Error               0                26d     100.96.113.72  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-mqrj7                         0/1     Error               0                27d     100.96.111.31  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-mrfc5                         0/1     Error               0                23d     100.96.112.64  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-nsppr                         0/1     Error               0                26d     100.96.110.73  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-pr5gt                         0/1     Error               0                23d     100.96.112.161 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-pwnkd                         0/1     Error               0                24d     100.96.113.134 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-r2jqx                         0/1     Error               0                28d     100.96.111.188 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-s79nt                         0/1     Error               0                24d     100.96.112.208 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-sbtgw                         0/1     Error               0                24d     100.96.110.182 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-spxdh                         0/1     Error               0                20d     100.96.114.38  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-t55cs                         0/1     Error               0                22d     100.96.105.200 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-tgms8                         0/1     Error               0                21d     100.96.120.252 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-wr4wk                         0/1     Error               0                24d     100.96.114.142 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-wtflw                         0/1     Error               0                27d     100.96.102.138 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-wwmjn                         0/1     Error               0                28d     100.96.105.65  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-controller-manager-65c486cddc-x9pht                         0/1     Error               0                24d     100.96.112.50  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-27n5g                                  0/1     Completed           0                24d     100.96.120.193 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-2kcpm                                  0/1     Completed           0                23d     100.96.101.243 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-4nlnv                                  0/1     Completed           0                26d     100.96.101.178 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-dc7jj                                  0/1     Completed           0                26d     100.96.101.84  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-lw25v                                  0/1     Completed           0                20d     100.96.105.226 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-mj799                                  0/1     Completed           0                20d     100.96.101.174 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-mk5ph                                  0/1     Completed           0                26d     100.96.29.94   
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-n6xpw                                  0/1     Completed           0                30d     100.96.113.172 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-pdqgx                                  0/1     Completed           0                20d     100.96.120.128 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-r98b5                                  0/1     Completed           0                31d     100.96.87.15   
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-sp5q8                                  0/1     Completed           0                25d     100.96.87.188  
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-t79wl                                  0/1     Completed           0                26d     100.96.112.233 
chaos-mesh                             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-xtzjr                                  0/1     Completed           0                28d     100.96.29.203  
mongodb-operator                       mongodb-kubernetes-operator-64c97679dc-4kwkm                      0/1     Error               0                5d21h   100.96.102.58 
zalando-postgres-operator              zalando-postgres-operator-94c6c7cf-54qn5                          0/1     Completed           0                3d15h   100.96.102.119
zalando-postgres-operator              zalando-postgres-operator-94c6c7cf-8hsbd                          0/1     Completed           0                20d     100.96.110.163
zalando-postgres-operator              zalando-postgres-operator-94c6c7cf-959kt                          0/1     Completed           0                25d     100.96.95.34  
zalando-postgres-operator              zalando-postgres-operator-94c6c7cf-9flkx                          0/1     Completed           0                26d     100.96.101.194
zalando-postgres-operator              zalando-postgres-operator-94c6c7cf-9jvnw                          0/1     Completed           0                4d15h   100.96.112.130
```

This is only a part of such pods in the cluster; there are many more of them

Here is the description of one of these pods:

```
Name:             chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4-pdqgx
Namespace:        chaos-mesh
Priority:         0
Service Account:  chaos-dashboard
Node:             xxxx
Start Time:       Mon, 22 Jan 2024 13:07:58 +0100
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/component=chaos-dashboard
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance=chaos-mesh
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=chaos-mesh
                  app.kubernetes.io/part-of=chaos-mesh
                  app.kubernetes.io/version=2.2.2
                  helm.sh/chart=chaos-mesh-2.2.2
                  pod-template-hash=6d46fcb8f4
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Failed
Reason:           Evicted
Message:          The node was low on resource: memory. 
IP:               100.96.120.128
IPs:
  IP:           100.96.120.128
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/chaos-dashboard-6d46fcb8f4
Containers:
  chaos-dashboard:
    Container ID:  containerd://ea09440c0dcc7f4434ad0da7aa5d6adb3024efc34cf68c98dac7679a2dddf9ab
    Image:         ghcr.io/chaos-mesh/chaos-dashboard:v2.2.2
    Image ID:      ghcr.io/chaos-mesh/chaos-dashboard@sha256:4e500d39a15aa710cff33b89ff25fe957de59c69fce6355ac7fd1e2d5c7e2b32
    Ports:         2333/TCP, 2334/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Command:
      /usr/local/bin/chaos-dashboard
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 22 Jan 2024 13:07:59 +0100
      Finished:     Mon, 22 Jan 2024 17:03:40 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:     25m
      memory:  256Mi
    Environment:
      CLEAN_SYNC_PERIOD:        12h
      DATABASE_DATASOURCE:      /data/core.sqlite
      DATABASE_DRIVER:          sqlite3
      LISTEN_HOST:              0.0.0.0
      LISTEN_PORT:              2333
      METRIC_HOST:              0.0.0.0
      METRIC_PORT:              2334
      TTL_EVENT:                168h
      TTL_EXPERIMENT:           336h
      TTL_SCHEDULE:             336h
      TTL_WORKFLOW:             336h
      TZ:                       UTC
      CLUSTER_SCOPED:           true
      TARGET_NAMESPACE:         chaos-mesh
      ENABLE_FILTER_NAMESPACE:  false
      SECURITY_MODE:            true
      GCP_SECURITY_MODE:        false
      GCP_CLIENT_ID:            
      GCP_CLIENT_SECRET:        
      DNS_SERVER_CREATE:        false
      ROOT_URL:                 http://localhost:2333
    Mounts:
      /data from storage-volume (rw)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  storage-volume:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
QoS Class:                   Burstable
```

Kubernetes version: v1.25.16

expecting that the garbage collector periodically passes through and deletes such pods.